# Java MVC architecture

Tags: java, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm developing an email client/server java application with RMI. I designed client based on MVC architecture. In particular, I've registered the Controller as a View event listener so that, for example, if I press the "inbox" button of the View, the Controller can download incoming emails from the server through a stub of the server itself.

The consequence of all this is that the controller is full of conditional code blocks on the name of the button pressed, which is very bad. Can anyone recommend me a way for replace conditional blocks? I thought about using some design patterns but I'd not know which is the best in this case.

Thanks!!

Comment: Register N listeners, one for each button.

Comment: How? For example, let's suppose we have something like this in the view:
btn1.addActionListener(controller);
btn2.addActionListener(controller);
btn3.addActionListener(controller);

But the Controller class can implement only one actionPerformed method.

Comment: If you posted your code instead of describing it, it would be easier to help

Comment: Please, post code of your view, I'll try to help

Comment: It's not MVC if the Controller is doing View logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing if/else statements

```
public class Controller implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if(....) {
           // action1
        } else if(...){
           // action2      
        }
    }
}
```

put every branch in an own method. E.g.

```
public class Controller {

    public void action1(){
        // ....
    }

    public void action2(ActionEvent ae){
        // ....
    }
}
```

Now you can use an anonymous `ActionListener` to delegate to the right method. E.g.

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
       controller.action1();
   }
});

btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
       controller.action2(ae);
   }
});
```

With Java 8 you can use method references or lambda expressions.

```
Controller controller = new Controller();

btn1.addActionListener(controller::action1);
btn2.addActionListener(ae -> controller.action2());
```

Comment: super easy and clean! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine you have 2 buttons on your view, let them be "Send" and "Close"
I think it's better to have two methods inside of controller, like `controller.onCloseClicked()` and `controller.onSendClicked()`.This way you can use two options:

1. implement one listener and add conditional code blocks to decide
   what method of controller to fire.
2. implement few listeners for buttons, one for each button and fire concrete method of contoller directly from them.

Why it's better? Sometimes you need to send not only event, but some bundle of data from ui(view) to controller. When you have one method per action it's easier to handle.